# Linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra

$V$ is a vector space over a field $\mathbb{R}$. Let $S,T$ be subspaces of $V$ with $S\cap T=\{\vec0\}$ and let $A$ be a set.

Suppose $f\in \text{ Fun}(A,S)$, $g\in\text{ Fun}(A,T)$, where $\text{Fun}(A,S)=\{f:A\to S \text{ is a function}\}$

Show that, regarded as vectors in $\text{Fun}(S,V)$, the vectors $f$ and $g$ are linearly independent.

First, suppose that $f,g$ are linearly dependent.

Then there exists not all zero $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $\alpha f+\beta\ g=\vec{0}$. ($\vec{0}(x)=0$ for all $x\in A$)

So $\forall x\in A$, $(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)=\vec{0}(x)\Leftrightarrow \alpha f(x)+\beta g(x)=0$

WLOG let $\alpha \neq0$. Then $f(x)=\frac{-\beta}{\alpha}g(x)$

So $f=\frac{-\beta}{\alpha}g\in \text{ Fun}(A,T)$

I can't find contradiction. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are several things missing in your post that caused some misconception.

First, you most likely mean that $f,g \in \text{Fun}(A,V)$ and not $f,g \in \text{Fun}(S,V)$.

Second, your task should be to show that these functions are linearly indepedent under the simple assumption that both aren't null functions.

Then all of it makes sense. The proof then gives you $f \in \text{Fun}(A,T)$, but since you know that $f \in \text{Fun}(A,S)$ you can tell as $S \cap T=\{0\}$ that $f(x)=0$ for all $x$ (i.e. $f$ is a null function) which contradicts your assumption of $f$ not being a null function.

PS: It's also important that $A$ is a *non-empty* set.